# How to resolve keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

Tags: java, certificate, runtime-error, keytool, truststore

I get the public cert from secure URL as below:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect portal.myshop.com:9043 < /dev/null | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout>/home/app/portalpublic.crt
```

and then add the public cert to trust store using the below command:

```
keytool -import -alias portalpubliccert -file /home/app/portalpublic.crt -storetype JKS -keystore cacerts
```

However, i get the below error in doing so:

```
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

Can you please suggest how can i fix this issue ?

```
cat -ev /home/app/portalpublic.crt

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----$
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA6iAD/I9U2kKAqEokzEkA$
b2QmPQb73A/bA9YD+I+pqEkqtwQmpe6Oiu3+mx2ppA/NXG2QqNb4IfpVEgRrQygG$
6giuhMikPRq6PQ7wywfxWaPkJDDcrLg7Dn8v3l5XgpeaFZN1KSGMDpdrsEpSlxFS$
ZaxDKUfySyjppsC9GV4Lv1IXET5sSmfYw2RqCkO/Q8zcItVkzjZIBw8Y/eVrloGm$
AnQj89cLJbDFq2VogVjMGdOSGQc7cQ0ZZAyrv0XV4hKpi9taiNNXv0ZKWuvk1oFo$
GyfildXPnVKORxSx6d865kj93fCsEXlLjJ1c8xHVr992hEWlWVthByqpTB7DVccj$
xQIDAQAB$
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----$
```

Comment: A public key is not a certificate. Off topic.

Comment: I get this error on a Temurin JDK but NOT on a older OpenJDK.  Wierd.

Answer (score 1):

Meta: this is not a programming or development problem, issue or question, and nowadays is likely to be closed. It would probably be suitable on security.SX or superuser.

> I get the public cert from secure URL as below:

> `openssl s_client ... | openssl x509 -pubkey ...`

**NO YOU DIDN'T.** You got the public key not the cert. The publickey is only a publickey and is not a cert, and a cert is not just a publickey although a cert (of the type here) *contains* a publickey. Also, you didn't get it 'from a URL'. You got it from a *domain name*, or more exactly from the host at or apparently at a domain name. A domain name is not a URL; *some* URLs (not all!) *contain* a domain name, but they are different things.

> `keytool -import ... -file ...`

`keytool -import[cert]` requires a certificate. A publickey is not a certificate. That's why the error message says the input is not a certificate -- because it isn't.

A Java keystore can store a certificate, specifically an X.509/PKIX-type certificate, as a trustedCertEntry, but it cannot store a bare publickey. If you want to store a certificate from the given URL in a keystore, get and then import the certificate -- NOT the publickey. If for some reason you want to store only the publickey, which is basically useless if it's not linked to the other information in the certificate, don't use a Java keystore and don't use `keytool`.

Comment: Got it Dave and thanks but can you share the command to get the certificate from the URL? Meanwhile I will search the Web.

Comment: I tried `echo | openssl s_client -servername myshop -connect  portal.myshop.com:9043 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > portalpublic.crt` but getting the same error.

Comment: That should work, and routinely does for me and (based on postings) at least thousands, probably millions, of other people. Look at the file: does it actually contain as expected the BEGIN line, base64 data, and END line? Can you add it to your Q (obviously if all details of your server are totally secret you can't)?

Comment: @djangofan: Temurin _is_ OpenJDK. First make sure this really is a certificate (a file _named_ .pem might not actually be PEM, and many PEM files are not certificates). If so ask a new question where this is appropriate, probably superuser or security.SX, and provide the cert, and say what error(s) you are getting and exactly what versions you are using to (try to) make it reproducible.

Comment: Turns out i was getting this error trying to download `/_explorer/explorer.pem` from cosmosdb, but my curl statement was whacked and it was downloading some html. (accident)